# JavaScript executing code after a false return

Tags: javascript

I am using a function to check if required fields are filled. I have these two functions, that should do the same, however the first one does not. Shouldn't javascript stop executing code, after it meets a return?

This functions returns true:

```
//Checks if various stages are ready
function trnReady(area) {
    switch (area)
    {
        case 'settings':
            $('input.required').each(function(){

                if($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }); 
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

While this one returns false:

```
//Checks if various stages are ready
function trnReady(area) {
    var r = true;
    switch (area)
    {
        case 'settings':
            $('input.required').each(function(){

                if($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    r = false;
                }
            }); 
        break;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I thought the first return would stop executing code? I'm wondering if it has anything to do with scope?

Comment: It does stop executing code... but only in the function where you did the `return`, which is the one passed to `.each()`.

Comment: The caller each does not return the return value of the function :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first code snippet `return false;` stops execution only of inner function passed to jquery *each* method. Also it stops jquery iteration accordingly to jquery API. But in any case trnReady returns true.

Second code snippet is correct, but you can optimise it, replacing `r = false;` to `return r = false;` (it will stop iteration by jquery when you already know that one of fields isn't filled)

Comment: Thank you for the optimization tip too!

Answer (score 3):

In the first snippet, the `return` applies to the function that is the argument of `each`. The `return` does not apply to the `trnReady` function. So, the `return false` is for the anonymous function in `each`.

In the second snippet, the `return` is correctly the `return` of the `trnReady` function, so it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Each of these functions contains a second function nested inside of it, and it's the returns inside the nested functions that you're expecting to take effect - but they don't. You can't return to the outer function's caller from the inner function. The best you can do is set a variable in the inner function, and then return that variable's value from the outer function, as your second example does.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, your function return `false` but only in scope of current case statement. Your `false` has any effect, any action is not invoked when it occured.

EDIT:
Return false has effect only inside anonymous function which you passed to `.each`.

Comment: The behavior that confused the OP is caused by the anonymous function in `each`, not the `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

the [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is an iterator that passes each object to your defined function.

When the defined function returns true, the iteration continues (to the next object)l
When the function return false, the iteration stops.

***But only the iteration is stopped***

The code hits `break`, but there is no other `return` statement to be executed in such a case.